# MongoDB authorization errors eventhough authorization isn't enabled

Tags: mongodb

I am using a fresh, simple install of MongoDB on Windows 10. No sharding, no replicas, and authorization is not enabled..yet I'm getting authorization errors.

I've been working on a Node app for over a week, and the problems started when I backed up the database with mongodump. Now when I run my app, I get:

`MongoError: not authorized on [database name] to execute command...`

And when I try to do mongorestore to a new database:

`Failed: [database name].[collection name]: error reading database: not authorized on [database name] to execute command`

What gives? If authorization isn't enabled, why is it producing authorization errors?

Comment: How do you know authorization is not enabled? Was it previously enabled before your fresh install? Did you `mongorestore` to this instance from the backup? And if so, did you specifically name a single database namespace, or did you you just restore the whole backup? The end logic being the `admin` database was probably part of the backup.

Comment: Authorization is not enabled in the config file. This install is less than a 6 months old because I was recently forced to upgrade Windows and reinstall everything, and I hadn't really used it until recently. Yes, I'm trying to mongorestore from the backup from a specific namespace.